# Catchall Router on Exim does not work

Tags: email, smtp, exim, catch-all

I have setup a catchall router on exim (used as last router):

```
catchall:
  driver = redirect
  domains = +local_domains
  data = ${lookup{*@$domain}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}
  retry_use_local_part
```

This works perfectly when sending emails locally. However, if I login to my GMail account and send an email to whatever@mydomain.com, then I get an "Unrouteable Address".

Thank you for any hints to solve this issue.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit for serverfault.com?

Comment: I've not been aware of serverfault.com - thanks for the hint. Anyway I won't be crossposting right now.

Answer (score 1):

In the system_aliases: section of the config file you already have a section which does the lookup in `/etc/aliases`.

Replace

```
data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}
```

with

`data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch*@{/etc/aliases}}`

and make sure you have `*:catchall_username*` in `/etc/aliases`

This works great for a single domain mail server which is already using `/etc/aliases`

Comment: Thanks for the tip - unfortunately I don't have a single-domain mailserver. So I would need to have a catchall for each domain individually.

Answer (score 0):

For this router to work, make sure that

1. mydomain.com is in local_domains
2. there is an entry for *@mydomain.com in /etc/aliases
3. MX record for mydomain.com is pointing to the server, where you've
   configured this

Comment: Mh - seems that everything is ok. What I did to make sure to match your guidelines:

1. setup of a catchall_domains list (making sure my domain is in the list)
   domainlist catchall_domains = +local_domains : mydomain.com
2. Entry is there. Locally I can send/receive these emails
3. MX pointing to my server, normal emails (non catch-all) work.

Thanks for further hints.

Answer (score 0):

This is old as heck, but I didn't see a good answer posted and someone else might want to know the answer.

This post is geared towards Debian with in single configuration file mode. It should work on any Linux Exim4 install though. For the purpose of explaining things we’ll use `test@example.com` which is configured with the hostname mail.example.com. The system will have a real user called test and we want to create an alias for test called alias. So the end result will all email sent to `alias@example.com` forwarded to `test@example.com` without having to create the user alias on the system.

First we need to create a place to store all of the alias files:

```
mkdir /etc/exim/aliases.d

vim /etc/exim/aliases.d/mail.example.com
```

contents of the alias file for mail.example.com alias:test

```
vim /etc/exim/exim4.conf.template
```

Now look for the section `system_aliases`. Here you’ll see `data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/aliases}}` or something similar. Change that to

```
data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/aliases.d/$domain}}
```

Save the file and restart exim. The alias should now work. To add support for other domains just add more alias files in the aliases.d directory with the correct hostname.

I copied and pasted this from my blog:

[0xeb.info](http://www.0xeb.info/)